# xorriso cannot find file in ISO image

Tags: iso, mkisofs

I'm trying to create a bootable ISO using `xorriso`, but I get this error:

```
xorriso : FAILURE : Cannot find in ISO image: -boot_image ... bin_path='<path to isolinux.bin that I specified>'
```

It's [not just me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cannot+find+in+ISO+image%22) who gas gotten this error. The message doesn't make sense either because I never used `-boot_image` and `xorriso` should not be looking for `isolinux.bin` in any ISO.

The path to `isolinux.bin` that I gave is the root directory of an already-unpacked ISO that I'm modifying.

Answer (score 1):

The message you get means that you gave a boot option mentioning
isolinux.bin as the boot image, but that the path to `isolinux.bin` is not
in the list of files which shall show up in the emerging ISO image.

-boot_image is the `xorriso` command which controls many boot related
properties. If you did not use it then I guess you used the `mkisofs`
emulation, where this was probably option -b (alias `-eltorito-boot`) which
expects the path *inside* the ISO, not in the filesystem from where your
files come.

So make sure to give with -b the path of isolinux.bin in the ISO.
In many ISOs, you will find it in `/boot/isolinux` or in `/isolinux`.
So if you just pack up a mounted ISO again, you will possibly have success
with

```
  -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin
```

or

```
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin
```

(The lack of trailing slash makes these paths compatible with `mkisofs` which
expects a relative path in the working directory of the source filesystem.
I.e. with `mkisofs` -b would work only if your `pwd` is the ISO's root.)

I could give clearer advise if you tell me the URL of the ISO which you
try to use as input and the `xorrisofs` options which you used.

Comment: It's the CD/DVD image for the Ubuntu 20.04.1 AMD64 desktop installer. The commands I'm using can be found on the Ubuntu help wiki page [InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) under the heading `AMD64 with isohybrid and UEFI`.